# how to delete embed yagpdb custom command

Tags: discord

(yagpdb custom command) i need to delete this embed 3 seconds after that it send, but `{{deleteResponse 3}}` doesn't work

```
{{ $id := reFind \d` .Cmd | toInt64 }}
{{ with (dbGet $id "afk") }}
    {{ $user := userArg .UserID }}
    {{ $eta := "" }}
    {{ if gt .ExpiresAt.Unix 0 }} {{ $eta = humanizeDurationSeconds (.ExpiresAt.Sub currentTime) | printf "*%s will be back in around %s.*" $user.Username }} {{ end }}
    {{ sendMessage nil (cembed
        "author" (sdict "name" (printf "%s está AFK" $user.String) "icon_url" ($user.AvatarURL "256"))
        "description" (joinStr "\n\n" $eta .Value)
        "color" (randInt 0 16777216)
        "footer" (sdict "text" "AFK desde")
        "timestamp" .UpdatedAt
    ) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked to put the embed in a variable and then send the message storing the message id in another variable. After sleep for the seconds I wanted to show the embed, I deleted the message via ID and the embeded part was included.

Your code would look like this:

```
{{ $id := reFind \d` .Cmd | toInt64 }}
{{ with (dbGet $id "afk") }}
    {{ $user := userArg .UserID }}
    {{ $eta := "" }}
    {{ if gt .ExpiresAt.Unix 0 }} {{ $eta = humanizeDurationSeconds (.ExpiresAt.Sub currentTime) | printf "*%s will be back in around %s.*" $user.Username }} {{ end }}
    {{ $embed := cembed
        "author" (sdict "name" (printf "%s está AFK" $user.String) "icon_url" ($user.AvatarURL "256"))
        "description" (joinStr "\n\n" $eta .Value)
        "color" (randInt 0 16777216)
        "footer" (sdict "text" "AFK desde")
        "timestamp" .UpdatedAt
     }} 
{{ $x := sendMessageRetID nil $embed }}
{{ sleep (3) }}
{{ deleteMessage nil $x }}
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete yagpdb's response after a certain time, you have to store the response & the id of the response in a variable. Here's the code for doing it.

```
{{ $x := sendMessageRetID nil $embed }}
{{deleteMessage nil $x 3}}
```

In the above code, the bot sends the embed storing the embed's id in the variable "x" & then deletes the message stored in the variable"x" after 3 seconds. I hope it helped you.